# plastic interlock screw ? this screw with no head

Tags: screws

How to remove this screw ?

[image]
Help me..

Comment: That does not appear to be a screw. Looks like a push-in retainer, like often used for auto trim.

Comment: no it's for a desk ? can i remove it ? ikea malm desk

Answer (score 3):

Those hammer in, so will be hard to remove in a way that makes them re-usable. You could try getting a putty knife or slot screwdriver under the head and prying, but you'll probably make a mess of it.

I've found that the nice people at the Ikea parts counter are pretty good about providing replacements if you show up with the old part (and, as you have, the part number).

Answer (score 1):

First drill a hole in the center, then mount a washer with a screw in the hole.
Protect the surface with thin sheet of wood and use a nail puller to pull the screw with the plastic item out of the material.

Dogyu is a well known manufacturer of nail pullers with broad shovels.